# Subscribing to the socket uses the state of the variable as empty. After Updating the state it's not using the state after updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setstate, stomp

I'm trying to connect to a socket endpoint that sends a JSON object every time either of the users sends messages back and forth.

I'm connecting to the socket and subscribing to a topic. Whenever the message is received it needs to add the object to the state. Since I'm using useEffect to connect the socket, it is called first and the socket gets subscribed to the topic with the empty state. So whenever a message is received, it is getting added to the empty array resulting in only one object.

Here's my code,

**The socket code**

```
const [chatData,setChatData] = useState([]);

  function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS(""); //I've connected to my backend socket
    console.log(chatData);
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
      isConnected = true;
      console.log("Connected: " + frame);
      stompClient.subscribe(
        "/topic/oneToOneChat/" + user.id,
        function (message) {
          const m = JSON.stringify(message.body);
          const socketMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(m));
          chatData.unshift(socketMessage); //Adding the object to the top of the array
          setChatData([...chatData]); //This is adding the object to the empty array
        }
      );
      stompClient.subscribe("/topic/oneToOneChat/" + id, function (message) {
        const m = JSON.stringify(message.body);
        const socketMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(m));
        chatData.unshift(socketMessage);
        setChatData([...chatData]);
      });
      stompClient.subscribe(
        "/topic/deleteOneToOneChat/" + id,
        function (message) {
          const m = JSON.stringify(message.body);
          const socketMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(m));
          deleteMessageFromChatData(socketMessage.id);
        }
      );
      stompClient.subscribe(
        "/topic/deleteOneToOneChat/" + user.id,
        function (message) {
          const m = JSON.stringify(message.body);
          const socketMessage = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(m));
          deleteMessageFromChatData(socketMessage.id);
        }
      );
    });
  }

 useEffect(() => {
     connect();
 }, [chatData]);
```

chatData is my state where I update my array of objects. After updating all the chats are showing on my screen. But when I send or receive the message, the socket is adding the message object to the chatData and removing all the previous messages. Since it is appending to the empty chatData.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by adding the below lines inside the socket subscription

```
setChatData((chats) => [socketMessage,...chats])
```